# Getting day of the week, switch statement/toString issues implementation of leap year aswell

Tags: java, switch-statement, tostring, dayofweek

I'm working on a little project for school and my group members and I struggling with a few things in our code. We need to write code for determining the day of the week, any given date would be on, we have the code for it, and we are using a switch statement to help assign the proper day for the equation output. For instance if the equation returns 0 it is Sunday, 1 it is Monday and so on.

This is what we have so far:

```
*/
public class Date {
  /**
   * Construct a date object.
   * @param year the year as integer, i.e. year 2010 is 2010.
   * @param month the month as integer, i.e. 
   *              january is 1, december is 12.
   * @param dayOfMonth the day number in the month, range 1..31.
   * PRECONDITION: The date parameters must represent a valid date.
  */
      private int year;
      private int month;
      private int dayOfMonth;

  public Date(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
      this.year = year;
      this.month = month;
      this.dayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
  }

  public enum Weekday { 
      MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, 
      THURSDAY, FRIDAY, 
      SATURDAY, SUNDAY };

  public String toString() {
      String theDate = month + " " + dayOfMonth + ", " + year;
      return theDate;
  }

  public boolean isLeapYear(){
        if ((this.year % 400 == 0)|| (this.year % 100 != 0 && this.year % 4 == 0))
                return true;
        else return false;
  /**
  * Calculate the weekday that this Date object represents.
  * @return the weekday of this date.
  */
  public String dayOfWeek() {


  int century = year/100; 

      int day = (dayOfMonth - month +  year +(year/4) + century) %7;
      Weekday i;
      switch(day){
      case 1:
           i = Weekday.MONDAY;
           System.out.println("The day of the week for this month is Monday.");
      case 2:
           i = Weekday.TUESDAY;
           System.out.println("The day of the week for this month is Tuesday.");
      case 3:
           i = Weekday.WEDNESDAY;
           System.out.println("The day of the week for this month is Wednesday.");
      case 4:
           i = Weekday.THURSDAY;
           System.out.println("The day of the week for this month is Thursday.");
      case 5:
           i = Weekday.FRIDAY;
           System.out.println("The day of the week for this month is Friday.");
      case 6:
           i = Weekday.SATURDAY;
           System.out.println("The day of the week for this month is Saturday.");
      case 0:
           i = Weekday.SUNDAY;
           System.out.println("The day of the week for this month is Sunday.");
        }
return i.name();
  }
}
```

We need to implement a `toString()` method and we are struggling to figure out what the dayOfWeek method should return. Also how should we implement our `isLeapYear()` method?

Comment: You seem to have assumed that every month has  a number of days that's one less than a multiple of 7.  I'm not sure whether you were thinking of 27 or 34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `break;` in you cases, Java executes all the subsequent `case` (until it finds a next break) if a matching `case` doesn't have a `break;`.

You need to initialize the `i` atleast with `null` (ideal would be to initialize with fallback day let's say the first day of week in case it doesn't go into any `case`)
`WeekDay i = null;` or `WeekDay i = WeekDay.SUNDAY;`

Also, you need to return (after the complete `switch`) `i.name()`.